# Certificate Chain incomplete using Let's Encrypt and Certes (Azure webrole)

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-web-roles, lets-encrypt

I am trying to create a new Let's Encrypt SAN certificate using the Certes Library and hosting on a Azure WebRole. Everything has worked previously (many times) but now I am getting a cert error on Android and ssllabs.com shows a certificate chain incomplete error.

The certificate is created without error and I have explicitly set FullChain = true on the PfxBuilder but I am unsure how to check if the full chain is recorded in the certificate correctly without uploading the certificate together with a new deployment (I am not a cert expert).

On the Azure Web role both the created certificate and the required Let's Encrypt Cert (Let's Encrypt Authority X3) are listed in the webrole certificates. I only uploaded the created certificate Azure adds the Let's Encrypt Authority X3 cert itself.

I am unsure whether it is a problem with the certificate not recording the full chain or some configuration setting on the WebRole. When I go to Certificates in the Azure Management console I see the Let's Encrypt Cert but when I rdp into the role and look in the IIS Manager I cannot see the Let's Encrypt Cert under Server Certificates. I also cannot find it when I open the Certificates Management Console (certlm).

I am starting to think it is a problem with the WebRole but I am at a loss on what to check next.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add additional `<Certificate>` element in your ServiceDefinition and ServiceConfiguration to specify the intermediate certs. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredevsupport/2010/02/24/how-to-install-a-chained-ssl-certificate/

**Edit due to broken link**
View your certificate. For each of the intermediate certificate between the root cert and your certificate, export the certificate file.

Upload these certificate to Azure

Add the `<Certificate>` element. You can get the thumbprint from the Azure portal.

Comment: Link is broken.